# Why public static AtomicBoolean variable is false during the test in Maven sometimes?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, testing, atomic

Why public static AtomicBoolean variable is false during the test in Maven sometimes?

Maybe, rude concurrency mistakes?

But works fine in Intellij.

```
public class MaintenanceFilterTest {
@Rule
public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();
private MaintenanceFilter target;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    target = new MaintenanceFilter();
    MaintenanceFilter.isMaintenanceStarted.set(false);
}

@Test
public void doFilterException() throws Exception {
    MaintenanceFilter.isMaintenanceStarted.set(true);
    expectedException.expect(MaintenanceException.class);
    expectedException.expectMessage
        ("Redeployment of application or restart of server is in progress.");

    target.doFilter(null, null, null);
}

public static class MaintenanceFilter implements Filter {
    public static final AtomicBoolean isMaintenanceStarted = new AtomicBoolean();

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
        ServletRequest input, 
        ServletResponse output, 
        FilterChain chain
    ) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        if (isMaintenanceStarted.get()) {
            throw new MaintenanceException
                ("Redeployment of application or restart of server is in progress.");
        }
    }//..
 }
}
```

Comment: default value of boolean is always `false`... whats the value which you are getting in Intellij ?

Comment: I am getting true.

Comment: Why make `isMaintenanceStarted` as static and change its value in before and during individual tests? Maven can run your tests in separate threads and can execute another `setUp()` that sets `isMaintenanceStarted` to false while another thread is executing your `target.doFilter(null, null, null);` method.

Comment: @tsolakp how fix this?

Comment: @Arthur Kharkivskiy just make it as instance variable and also dont need to use `AtomicBoolean`.

Comment: @tsolakp but I need to change it from one servlet.

Comment: If you cant change `isMaintenanceStarted` then make sure not to run Maven tests in parallel. See if it will help.

Comment: @tsolakp did not helped( could u check on ur pc? plus this method  //monkey Test
    public void doFilter() throws Exception {
        MaintenanceFilter.isMaintenanceStarted.set(false);

        target.doFilter(null, null, null);
    }

Comment: <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>always</forkMode>          
                </configuration>

Comment: Please clearly state what your expected outcome is, and what the actual outcome is, with a stack trace for the latter if applicable.

Comment: @WarrenDew I am expecting exception:  expectedException.expectMessage
        ("Redeployment of application or restart of server is in progress.");

    target.doFilter(null, null, null);

Comment: but in Maven it goes without exception.

Comment: @Arthur Kharkivskiy it works and passes the test with my maven build.

Comment: @tsolakp do u have <forkMode>always</forkMode> ? thx!!

Comment: I dont have maven-surefire-plugin defined in my pom at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not noticed

```
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
```

in my maven-surefire-plugin.